# Catch Facebook Oauth error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I am faced with a bit of a puzzle.
I built a Facebook login that can be configured by whoever uses it.
The problem I am facing is due to the scope errors thrown if an invalid one is configured.
Facebook shows a error window that I would very much like to avoid and instead get the error back to my code for handling.

I have been up an down the Facebook developers site and Googled all day yesterday and all the info I find is related to the PHP API not the JavaScript SDK or is totally off topic information.

My code is like this:

```
    FB.init({
        appId:      fAuthentication.options.fAppId,
        channelUrl: fAuthentication.options.fChannelUrl,
        status:     fAuthentication.options.fStatus,
        cookie:     fAuthentication.options.fCookie,
        xfbml:      fAuthentication.options.fXfbml
    });
    FB.login(function (response) {
        fAuth.fLogin(response);
    },
    {scope: fAuth.options.fScope});
```

If the `fScope` option contains a invalid scope I get the Facebook pop-in window with this error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: invalid permissions: err
```

Is there any way to prevent it and get the error to my code somehow?

Comment: A normal user will only see the first line of the error message, the following lines are only shown to the developer of the app. If you want to prevent users from giving invalid values – then just let them choose from a list of given values.

Comment: It is quite the list. I would rather not add it to the script cause Facebook may at any time deprecate some and add others.